# could not find module 'Alamofire' for target 'arm64-apple-ios-simulator'; found: x86_64-apple-ios-simulator, x86_64

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swift5, xcode12

I have updated xcode to 12.3, i am getting the new errors.

- could not find module 'Alamofire' for target 'arm64-apple-ios-simulator'; found: x86_64-apple-ios-simulator, x86_64
- Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code

Comment: Have you solved this problem?

Comment: no, I have tried SPM and Pod but no help @Johnny

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. Have you found the solution?

Comment: No. This issue still exists for me. @ErickSilva

Comment: Which version of Alamofire are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another workaround is to set BuildSettings ->"Validate Workspace" to Yes. It will still show a warning, but will build the project.

[image]

Comment: This didn't help @Babar

Comment: I have added arm64 to **excluded architecture** and set **Build Active Architecture Only** to true but still am getting this error. @babar

Answer (score 0):

I was using Carthage 0.38 and XCode 13. I encountered this issues when building Moya.

I found that in file **Carthage > Build > iOS**, there is a duplicate Alamofire framework build (another one is in Carthage > Build), and XCode somehow use this for building Moya.

After I deleted the duplicate one, it can be built successfully.

Answer (score -11):

change your project name
use only english characters

Comment: I have added arm64 to **excluded architecture** and set **Build Active Architecture Only** to true but still am getting this error.